# Spotify API client get playlist tracks offset

Tags: c#, wpf, api, spotify, offset

I am a complete newbie to APIs and wanted to try it out with the Spotify API.

I use the [Spotify API client from JohnnyCrazy](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy) and it works quite well so far.
The authentication with the token works too.

As a test I wanted to display all songs of a given playlist, but found out that there is a request limit of 100 songs.
To get the next songs I would have to use the query parameter `offset` as I read on the [Spotify Developer website](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlists-tracks/).

My question now is how to include the `offset` parameter in the code with the Spotify API client.

This is my code:

```
var spotify = new SpotifyClient(MyToken);

var playlist = await spotify.Playlists.Get(MyPlaylistURI);

foreach (PlaylistTrack<IPlayableItem> item in playlist.Tracks.Items)
{
  if (item.Track is FullTrack track)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(track.Name, track.Album.Name);
  }
}
```

edit: MyPlaylistURI is just the Playlist ID. my bad

Comment: Can you post the `MyPlaylistURI` you are building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlists-tracks/), `offset` is a query parameter, meaning that you can just append it to the URI, i.e.

```cs
var MyPlaylistURI = "https://uri-you-are-using?offset=100"
var spotify = new SpotifyClient(MyToken);
var playlist = await spotify.Playlists.Get(MyPlaylistURI);
```

Of course, you would not hard code the offset. This is just to show how to include that parameter.

Comment: Yeah sorry for bad naming. spotify.Playlists.Get() takes the PlaylistID not the URI. My bad